# Duplicated entry at building Android application

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm building android application and I have problem to build it. My  `build.gradle` file contains:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nakupniseznam"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'aars'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
        }
    }

    compile files('libs/notification-hubs-0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/azure-notifications-handler-1.0.1.jar')

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@jar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
}
```

And the build error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/microsoft/windowsazure/notifications/BuildConfig.class
```

Still the same error. 
Try to exclude multidex, but without success and I really don't know why :(

Comment: Check your jar files. You are adding twice the com/microsoft/windowsazure/notifications/BuildConfig class

Comment: yes, I see duplicated BuildConfig class in multidex. I  have tried to exlude that but without success. Any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this line...  `compile files('libs/azure-notifications-handler-1.0.1.jar')`...  handled by this line... `compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@jar'`? That looks like a duplicate entry to me

Comment: even if I comment one of the compile declaration, apps is not running. Always crash on: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.microsoft.windowsazure.notifications.NotificationsManager$1` :(